# Method of Moments and Maximum Liklihood

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose you have a sample with the following values and their respective frequencies:

Values: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Frequency: 25 10 7 3 2 1 1 1

Assume the geometric distribution applies:

p(k)= p(1-p)$^{k-1}$

Estimate the value of p by:

a) Using method of moments

b) Using maximum liklihood

Not sure where to start with this. After doing some research, it looks like the method of moments gives an estimate of p = $\frac{1}{X}$ but what is X? The mean of the 8 given frequencies?

Comment: The method of moments says "choose the parameters so that the first moment, second moment, etc. agree, up until your conditions already uniquely specify all parameters". In this simple case it means that your estimate for $p$ is $\frac{1}{\overline{X}}$ where $\overline{X}$ is the mean of the sample, i.e. $\frac{25 \cdot 1 + 10 \cdot 2 + \dots + 1 \cdot 8}{25+10+\dots+1}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, and the maximum likelihood would be the same, no? Just 1/X?

Comment: It appears to turn out that way in this particular case, but that is not always how it turns out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum Likelihood

> Let $K_1 \ldots K_n$ **(in your case: $\pmb{n = 25*1 + 10*2 + 7*3 + \ldots + 8*1}$)** be random samples with pmf:
>   $$f\left(k;p \right)={\left(1-p \right)}^{k-1}p, \quad k=1,2,3....$$
>   The likelihood function is given by:
>   $$L\left(p \right)={\left(1-p \right)}^{{k}_{1}-1}p {\left(1-p \right)}^{{k}_{2}-1}p...{\left(1-p \right)}^{{k}_{n}-1}p ={p}^{n}{\left(1-p \right)}^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{k}_{i}-n}$$
>   In your case, $K_1 =\ldots =K_{25} = 1$, and $K_{26} = \ldots = K_{35} = 2$ and so on..
>   Taking log,
>   $$lnL\left(p \right)= nln{p}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{k}_{i}-n \right)ln{\left(1-p \right)}$$
>   Differentiating and equating to zero, we get,
>   $$\frac{d\left[lnL\left(p \right)\right]}{dp}=\frac{n}{p} -\frac{\left(\sum_{1}^{n}{k}_{i}-n \right)}{\left(1-p \right)}=0 \rightarrow p^* =\frac{n}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{k}_{i} \right)}$$
>   Finally, the ML estimator of $p$, i.e. $\hat{p}^{ML}$, is the solution of the above equation by using the sample data , namely:$$\hat{p}^{ML}=\frac{n}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{K}_{i} \right)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{K}_{i} \right)}{n}} =\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(K_i)}$$
>   where $\mathbb{E}(K_i)$ is the sample mean of data.

Method of Moments

> Now, via MoM (method of moments):
>   \begin{equation}\label{eq16}
> \begin{split}
> \mathbb{E}(K) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}
> kp(1-p)^{k}
> &=
> p\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}
> k(1-p)^{k}
> \\&=
> \frac{p}{1 - (1-p))^2}
> \\&=
> \frac{1}{p}
> \end{split}
> \end{equation}
>   where again the MoM estimate is $\hat{p}^{MoM} = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}(K_i)}$ is the inverse of the sample mean of data.

Thanks @Ian for the correction

Comment: You say "pdf" but you mean "pmf".

Comment: Thanks for that .. Yes pmf, the variables are discrete

Comment: So I got that the answer is p= 1/X = 1/2.18 = .4587 for both of them. What does that value of p actually mean exactly? Like what does it represent?

Comment: Hi @JohnH.. So this is a Maximum Likelihood estimate of $p$, which is an interesting estimate with many nice features. It is simply the estimate the maximises the likelihood (thus the name Maximum likelihood).. This is one way of estimating probability parameters from data: other examples might be "given data from a normal distribution, estimate the mean/variance of the data", and so on..

Comment: So if you were to graph the results, by values and their respective probabilities, .4587 would be its peak?

Comment: What do you mean by "graph the results" ? As in, frequency vs values ?

Comment: If you graph the likelihood function, which is a product of all the separate probabilities for each element of your sample, its peak would be at 0.4587. You could actually try to do this with the likelihood function that El Bazzi wrote for you, though the result is a rather high degree polynomial so it might be kinda hard to look at (because of scale problems).

Comment: Im just confused in this particular case what .4587 is the maximum likelihood of.

Comment: Yes as @Ian said.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: It means, based on the given data that you have, p = .4587 maximises the Likelihood function

Comment: Actually, the likelihood function looks quite nice; plot $p^{50}(1-p)^{59}$ from $p=0$ to $p=1$ and see how it looks.